# Java Date format. String to date

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have a String that contains a date.

I'm trying to do so but it gives me an error.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Mar 20 20:44:49 CET 2015" (at offset 0)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

I'm trying this.

```
String fechaFestivo = c.getString(1);//Fri Mar 20 20:44:49 CET 2015

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(fechaFestivo);
```

Comment: Try this `DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: @Skizo Did you try your solution? It isn't work...

Comment: I tried your solution (as well as the one of @Skizo) and both are working for me (only change is that I hardcoded `Fri Mar 20 20:44:49 CET 2015`). Are you sure about fechaFestivo string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `SimpleDateFormat` for `DateFormat`, something like that :

```
String fechaFestivo = c.getString(1); //Fri Mar 20 20:44:49 CET 2015

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(fechaFestivo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` is using the default locale, which may not be English. In that case, the abbreviated name of the day will not be recognized.

Make sure to use the correct locale with this [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"